# как сделать метки на линии цены в matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Делаю визуализацию графика биржи в питон с использованием matplotlib, сейчас выглядит так - линия цены просто линия,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а хотелось бы видеть на ней ценовую отметку, как например здесь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как это можно исправить? на всякий случай код

```
import ccxt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

import config

exchange = ccxt.bybit({
    'api_key': config.api_key,
    'secret': config.secret,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    "options": {'defaultType': 'future'}
})

plt.ion()
for _ in iter(int, 1):
    # получаем последние свечи
    bars = exchange.fetch_ohlcv('BTC/USDT:USDT', timeframe='1m', limit=100)
    df = pd.DataFrame(bars[:-1], columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])



    # цвет фона
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.set(facecolor="black")
    # вид линий основной сетки:
    ax.grid(which='major',
            color='white',
            linewidth=0.1)

    # вид линий вспомогательной сетки:
    ax.grid(which='minor',
            color='white',
            linewidth=0.1,
            linestyle=':')

    # включить второстепенные деления осей:
    ax.minorticks_on()

    # линия цены
    price = exchange.fetch_ticker('BTC/USDT:USDT')['last']
    plt.axhline(y=price,
                color='red',
                linewidth=0.5,
                linestyle='--')

    y = df['close']
    plt.plot(y, color='lightgreen')
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)

    plt.clf()
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала маленький совет. Я уверен, что ответ бы вы получили намного быстрее, если бы выделили из своего скрипта только то, что относиться к вопросу и показали тут (как того требуют правила данного ресурса) . А так по сути вы заставляете желающих вам помочь импортировать некую весьма специфическую библиотеку и не одну, потом экспериментировать с никому не интересными (кроме вас)  графиками, разбираться, что-же там надо сделать. Мало найдется желающих. У меня -  точно такого желания нет. Поэтому вам, как новичку я помогу, приведя пример того, как можно показать в matplotlib на линейном графике метку, значение которой определяется в коде, равно как и ее положение на графике. А уж "прилаживать" мой пример к вашему коду - вам придется самому.
Итак:

```
x=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
y=np.random.normal(size=100)
plt.plot(x,y)
y_c=y.mean()+1
plt.hlines(y_c,0,10,color='r')
plt.text(10+0.6, y_c, y_c, size=10, 
         ha="center", va="center",
         bbox=dict(boxstyle="round",
                   ec=(1., 0.5, 0.5),
                   fc=(1., 0.8, 0.8),
                   )
         )
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь, принцип понятен, а экспериментировать с тонкой настройкой графика -  оставляю вам. Останутся вопросы -  задавайте.

Comment: спасибо это как раз то что надо

Answer (score -1):

можно сделать через добавление своей метки на оси:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = list(range(0, 10))
Y = np.random.randint(400, high=500, size=len(X))

my_val = 470 ## <---
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X, Y)
plt.axhline(y=my_val, color='red', linewidth=0.5, linestyle='--')
ax.set_yticks(np.append(ax.get_yticks(), my_val))
plt.gca().get_yticklabels()[-1].set_bbox(dict(edgecolor="red", facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]